# Is there a Stack Exchange website for ethical hacking?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, stack-exchange

I am very excited to learn Ethical Hacking. Is there any Stack Exchange website or any other website were likely minded people share there experience and I learn from them and share my ideas too?

Comment: Is this question really the duplicate of that one?

Answer (score 3):

You can ask and answer questions on Ethical Hacking at https://security.stackexchange.com/